# Firebase Cloud Function Braintree unexpectedError with Blaze Plan

Tags: google-cloud-functions, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I have a firebase cloud function and want to enable payments via braintree under that function.

I have a upgraded Blaze Plan for firebase but the braintree is still throwing that **unexpectedError**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

var braintree = require("braintree");

var gateway = braintree.connect({
                            environment: "Sandbox",
                            merchantId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                            publicKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                            privateKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                            });
```

Studying various on SO almost all posts are pointing that you must upgrade your plan but I am already in blaze plan.

Comment: An Unexpected error can also been thrown by syntax errors. Plx check if your code is fine. You can try to run most of it localy on your device just to be sure. Did you also try to redeploy your function after you changed the plan?

Comment: @TarikHuber I am seeing Connection Refused from inside the braintree library

Comment: Do you see that in your functions console or in a local nodejs script?